# Replacing a charged capacitor with suitable components to form equivalent circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, components

If we have an initially charged capacitor (say 5V) and capacitance C, in a circuit, can we replace it with a constant voltage source of 5V and an uncharged capacitor with same capacitance C, both in series?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: While solving transient analysis circuits, it becomes quite easier to write equations and  to solve the circuit.

Comment: Hmm. Does it? I'm not so sure, but if it works for you (and someone can show you that it's demonstrably equivalent, which I haven't bothered working through a proof), then go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  By the same token you can put a current source in parallel with an inductor, to reach the same end.

Comment: How does the initial current through the inductor ever get to zero if you connect it to a resistor, say?

Comment: @Chu I'm not sure what picture you may have in your head.  The inductor/current source and capacitor/voltage source are analogous cases.  In either case the source needs to be connected to the idealized components, with any non-ideal bits (i.e., resistances in the inductor) modeled outside of the ideal component.  And in both cases, as the state of the part (voltage for the cap, current for the coil) goes to zero this is seen in the model as the state reaching the equal but opposite value of the source -- so a 5V source in series with a cap would decay to the cap having -5V, for a sum of 0V.

Comment: I'm trying to picture an inductor with a current at t=0-, being modelled by an inductor with a parallel current source.

Comment: ... if you have a current source in parallel with an inductor, then all the source current goes through the inductor, regardless of whatever else may be connected, because it's a short circuit.

Comment: The OP's notion is to start the capacitors (and presumably inductors) with zero initial states, and simulate a non-zero initial state with a source.

Comment: I didn't read the OP that way.

Answer (score 1):

A capacitor C charged with u(t=0) = Va follows these equations:

[image]

An uncharged capacitor C and a voltage source Va in series follow these equations:

[image]

They are equivalent as they follow the same i-v equations.